# RAM on an Ubuntu Mac Mini?

Tags: 12.04, mac, ram

I have a 2011 Mac Mini with 4GB RAM, I'm planning on wiping it and installing Ubuntu. But since I'm gonna be running a gaming server on it, (MineCraft), I wanted to know how much RAM the computer can take, this means the limits of the Mac Mini hardware with the amount of RAM Ubuntu supports.

So does anybody know what the highest RAM this combo can take?

Comment: Ubuntu can take a lot of RAM.. so the  only thing to worry about is the RAM limit in the Mac mini motherboard.

Comment: i know this so how much can the mac hardware take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and the Ubuntu software supports extremly high ram limits but the 8gb everybody brings up is the Mac OS X software limitation of ram, so technicly hardware wise, the Mac mini 2010, that i have can support up to 16gb ram hardware wise.